# How to access aggregate and concatenated fields from a joined subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, aggregate-functions

Here is a bit of pseudocode to represent what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT A.ID
     --, B.DESCRIPTION
     --, B.YEAR     
  FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID
                 , DESC1 || ' : ' || DESC2 AS "Description"
                 , MAX(YEAR)
              FROM TABLE_B
          GROUP BY ID
                 , DESC1 || ' : ' || DESC2) B
                ON A.ID = B.ID
```

As it stands, this query will run just fine. If I uncomment the two fields individually from the SELECT statement, each one will give me an invalid identifier error.

How can I access these aggregated and concatenated fields from this subquery?

Comment: Give some sample data for both tables as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't alias with double quotes if you don't need to.

You need to alias the MAX(YEAR) as YEAR for it to be referenced properly.

```
SELECT A.ID
   , B.DESCRIPTION
   , B.YEAR     
  FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID
                 , DESC1 || ' : ' || DESC2 AS DESCRIPTION
                 , MAX(YEAR) AS YEAR
              FROM TABLE_B
          GROUP BY ID
                 , DESC1 || ' : ' || DESC2) B
                ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. What is the difference between aliasing with and without double quotes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, but not 100%, that when you apply double quotes on your alias, you will implicitly impart case sensitivity on the alias name.

Comment: @unleashed , You are right, in Oracle all precompiled PL/SQL block and SQL queries stores in upper case, and SQL processor and PL/SQL processor bring code to uppercase, If you do need the case sensitive literals , for example to access via heterogeneous DB link to MS SQL DB objects which are case sensitive, in that case you should use quoted literals, or if you need to create XML from  Oracle object type  using XMLType    and tags in xml must be case sensitve then you can define your type members quoted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like below will give you what you need. I used another join based on `year` and `id`. May be if you give some sample data and exact expected output, there might be a better approach as well.

```
SELECT A.ID
 ,B.DESCRIPTION
 ,B.YEAR     
FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN 
    (select b1.* from table_b b1
    inner join 
        (SELECT ID
        , DESC1 || ' : ' || DESC2 AS "Description"
        , MAX(YEAR)
        FROM TABLE_B
        GROUP BY ID
        , DESC1 || ' : ' || DESC2
        ) b2
    on b1.id=b2.id and b1.year=b2.year
    ) B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```